# How would you correlate time series (price changes) to a discrete event happening?

Tags: time-series, discrete-data

I'm not sure what kind of model you would use here...

But say you are looking at the price of the S&P 500.  Suppose...  If the market trends up, then everyone is happy and more likely to spend.  If the market trends down and everyone tightens their belts and spending slows down.

Ok, so say I'm looking at people who buy big airplanes.  They make an offer and it's accepted pending inspection / financing / paperwork.  They also have an option to walk away for whatever reason.  Say this process takes roughly 30 days.

So if you make the offer on the plane and it's accepted, and all of a sudden the S&P 500 drops... you're more likely to walk away and not buy the aircraft.  If the S&P 500 drops a LOT, then you're even LESS likely to buy the aircraft.  If the S&P 500 jumps up a LOT, then you're very likely to buy the aircraft.

Ok, so a drop in the market doesn't necessarily happen after one day...  A drop could be in one day, over a sustained period like a week, or even the entire month that I am considering buying the aircraft.  So the strategy proposed here doesn't make much sense to me:
[How to test for correlation between frequency of an event and the stock market](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/109509/how-to-test-for-correlation-between-frequency-of-an-event-and-the-stock-market)

So how should you account for "upwards and downwards pressure" on the likelihood of an event happening?

I'm not even sure if I'm phrasing the question correctly, but if you've made it this far, thank you for sticking with it.

Comment: Does it make sense to use stock volatility as the measure for the event of "walking away" happening? Take a look at the examples section: https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/getting_started/

Comment: Maybe not... the direction of the change is also important.